# core-animated-pages hero transition z-index

Tags: polymer

I am trying to implement a "topeka"-like UI (http://www.polymer-project.org/apps/topeka/) web-application with polymer. Here it is a preview (http://nautes-dashboard.herokuapp.com/) and this the following url is my project github page (https://github.com/NikZar/nautes-freedomotic-dashboard).

As you can see there is a problem (I think related to the *nautes-box* element z-index, since all the *nautes-box* elements will get the same *z-index*), when the hero transition rolls back to the main dashboard (f.e. tapping on *environments*, and the back arrow. Instead the *triggers* *nautes-box* works fine since it is the last sibling added).

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue? Is it really related to the element *z-index* or to the transition *z-index*?

I both tried to give an higher z-index to the *environments nautes-box*, to its section and to the *core-animated-pages transition* but it changed nothing... Looking at the topeka code I have seen a needZ attribute in the *topeka-categories* CSS. Am I missing something?

PS: the https certificate is self signed, ajax request will fail if you don't try to access the api page first (https://fritz.bestmazzo.it:9113/) ...it's a feature :)

Answer (score 0):

please check:
[polymer-tile-window](https://github.com/teaegg/polymer-tile-window)